# Pick event on a PatchCollection object doesn't target clicked artist

Tags: python, matplotlib

I have a collection of patches grouped into a PatchCollection which is then added to the axes as a collection. A callback for a pick event is established. When I click on one of the patches, the pick event fires and callback is invoked but the artist member of the event is the PatchCollection object instead of the artist object that was clicked. How can I determine the clicked artist without having to test each patch?

```
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
from matplotlib.patches import Circle, Rectangle
from matplotlib.collections import PatchCollection
import numpy as np

def onclick(event):
    if event.xdata is not None:
        print('%s click: button=%d, x=%d, y=%d, xdata=%f, ydata=%f' %
          ('double' if event.dblclick else 'single', event.button,
           event.x, event.y, event.xdata, event.ydata))

def onpick(event):
    print("artist=", event.artist)

    #print("You picked {:s}, which has color={:s} and linewidth={:f}".format( \
    #    event.artist, event.artist.get_color(), event.artist.get_linewidth()))

N = 25

fig = plt.figure(figsize=(5,5))
ax = fig.add_subplot(111, aspect='equal')
ax.set_axis_bgcolor('0.8')

ax.set_xlim([0,1])
ax.set_ylim([0,1])

xpts = np.random.rand(N)
ypts = np.random.rand(N)
patches = []
for x,y in zip(xpts,ypts):
    circle = Circle((x,y),0.03)
    patches.append(circle)

colors = 100 * np.random.rand(len(patches))
p = PatchCollection(patches, alpha=.5, picker=2)
p.set_array(np.array(colors))
ax.add_collection(p)

#cid = fig.canvas.mpl_connect('button_press_event', onclick)
pid = fig.canvas.mpl_connect('pick_event', onpick)

plt.show()
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The idea of a collection is that there are no single patches. Otherwise it would be a simple list of existing patches. So there is no way to get a single patch from the collection, because it doesn't exist.

If you are interested in getting some of the properties of the clicked collection members, you can use the `event.ind`. This is the index of the clicked member(s).

You can use this index to obtain the information from the collection properties:

```
def onpick(event):
    if type(event.artist) == PatchCollection:
        for i in event.ind:
            color = event.artist.get_facecolor()[i]
            print("index: {}, color: {}".format(i,color))
```

would print something like

```
# index: 23, color: [ 0.279566  0.067836  0.391917  0.5     ]
```

Comment: I guess I missed the part in the documentation about homogenizing all the patches into a collection. I assumed it simply maintained as a list. Anyway, this gives me enough to figure which patch, or patches were clicked.